# Segment Tree in updating an Array

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

This is a ongoing programming competition [Problem](http://www.codechef.com/JULY15/problems/ADDMUL/).Here we have to update an array using 4 types of operation
**Query 1 : 1 x y v** 

This implies adding v to array A to all the indices from x to y

**Query 2 : 2 x y v**
 This implies multiplying the scalar v with the array A for all the indices from x to y

**Query 3 :** 3 x y v This implies initializing the array A at all the indices from x to y with the value v
**Query 4 : 4 x y**
This is a report query which needs to find the sum of the values in A from x to y

I have solve the problem using **Segment Tree.** I am quite sure my solution is correct as I try multiple query and getting the right answer.
But i am failing my Test Cases I have tried multiple time but can't figure out where i have done mistake.
I have solved it using **Lazy propgation** mainting an Array **Level[3][n]**

```
Level[0][n] is for addition update
Level[1][n] is for multiplication update
Level[2][n] is for Resetting the Value
```

Here is my [Full Working Code](http://ideone.com/tfP8CX)
 I banging my heads for past few days but can't figure out what i have done wrong
I have tried with multiple input and getting the right answer but could not figure out why it is failing
Please Help Me
Thanks.

Comment: I posted the idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233990/how-do-i-efficiently-multiply-a-range-of-values-of-an-array-with-a-given-number/31234737#31234737 - with this you only need to figure out how to do the third type of query. That is a lot of code and it's not likely anyone will spend time debugging it. At least narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @IVlad i am quite sure my solution is correct can you give me some input where my code fails that would be helpful